# Facebook thumbnail never works properly (Open Graph)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

The Goal: There will be a Facebook [like] and [send] option underneath all our products and it will show the proper thumbnail image.

The problem: All the OG (open graph) tags are in place.  According to [Facebook's test](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://dev.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetailView.aspx?StyleId=1044214), it works.  I can see the preview image (as I should) on their *test site*.  There, it works!  In reality, this doesn't work at all.  Outside of Facebook's test page.. it NEVER has worked.

[Direct link to an example page showing the problem](http://dev.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetailView.aspx?StyleId=1044214)

The Open Graph tags are in place, including this:

```
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.loveculture.com/ProductImages/1044214_15_1.jpg" />`
```

Now it's randomly choosing images through out the page.  I am beyond frustrated.

I'd like to rule out a few things.

Yes, the images are on a subdomain.  Even using images on the same domain gives random thumbnails.
Yes, I've contacted Facebook about this and the issue was ignored.  I'm losing hope on this issue.

**UPDATE**
Great.... Now it decided to use one of the pink arrows for the thumbnail image.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to the Facebook debugger it doesn't work:

> **Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed:**
>
> Tiny og:image: All the images referenced by og:image must be at least **200px in both dimensions**. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

The file you are passing is 180x258px. Pass the full size image and it should be fine.

Comment: I wish that was the fix.  I just updated it to view larger pics.  The Facebook Open Graph test shows one warning now.

Comment: The test is showing the proper image I need to show within the test.  Grrrrrrrrr.  Now the images are 350x460.  :-/  Still not actually working.

Comment: Give it a few hours for Facebook to update their cache and check again. It should correct itself now that you've corrected the images.

Comment: I really hope so....  If it doesn't work, no harm.  I truly appreciate your responses.  Thank you.

Comment: I get this warning now: `'og:locale:locale => en_US``

Comment: Yes, that's the unresolved warning.  The locale tag is definitely in the code... `meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"

Ok, I just took out this property.  ZERO warnings.  Ok, I feel slightly better (still doesn't work).  I'll check back in a few hours to see if this is a cache issue from Hell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved. Thank you all.

The issue was within the URL used within the HTML.

`<div class='fb-like' data-send='true' data-width='450' data-href='http://www.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetailView.aspx?StyleId=1043361' data-show-faces='true'></div>`

It was a war between two legit urls.
http://www.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetailView.aspx?StyleId=1043361 
vs
http://www.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetail.aspx?StyleId=1043361

I'm glad this has been resolved.